# Magento, how i can send variable from MyController to my view phtml?

Tags: magento, view, controller

how i can send variable from MyController to my view phtml?

Zend framework, i send like this:

// MyController

```
$this->view->name = "Matheus";
```

or

```
$this->view->assign('name',"matheus");
```

// My View

```
echo $this->name;
```

in Magento Controller, how i send from MyController to my view, and how i can see in my view the variable?

thanks!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Magento MVC is different to Zend one, it is configuration based. View in magento consists of 2 parts - block (class) and template plus layout update in xml file. It can't be described in 2 words, you should read this [article](http://www.magentocommerce.com/knowledge-base/entry/magento-for-dev-part-4-magento-layouts-blocks-and-templates).